# Xamarin.iOS RegisteredForRemoteNotifications not called

Tags: c#, push-notification, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am using Xamarin Forms and am currently trying to get push notifications to work with the iOS project. I have followed [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/user-notifications/deprecated/remote_notifications_in_ios/)  Xamarin guide to add notifications to my iOS app but the RegisteredForRemoteNotifications method is never called.

I have also created both push notification certificates and enabled background notifications. Even FailedToRegisterForRemoteNotifications is never called.

What can I do?

PS: I'm using an iPhone 5s with iOS 10 so I also read [this](https://blog.xamarin.com/getting-started-with-the-ios-10-notification-framework/) post on the User Notifications Framework.

[image: Certificates]
[image: Provisioning Progile]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, after publishing in the AppStore it starts working...

Comment: Is uploading to AppStore enough to receive notifications or it should be Ready for Sale?

Answer (score 5):

Points for noticing the big note at the top of the Xamarin guide, a lot of people sometimes gloss over them.

> NOTE: The information in this section pertains to iOS 9 and prior, it
>   has been left here to support older iOS versions. For iOS 10 and
>   later, please see the User Notification Framework guide for supporting
>   both Local and Remote Notification on an iOS device.

It would have been nice to see some of your own code sample, but that's neither here nor there.

So as you said you plan on using iOS 10 devices, here is the code we use that works from 10.3 backwards.This code is in our FinishedLaunching() method inside the AppDelegate class.

```
            if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(10, 0))
            {
                // iOS 10 or later
                var authOptions = UNAuthorizationOptions.Alert | UNAuthorizationOptions.Badge | UNAuthorizationOptions.Sound;
                UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.RequestAuthorization(authOptions, (granted, error) =>
                {
                    if (granted)
                    {
                        InvokeOnMainThread(() => {
                            UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotifications();
                        });
                    }
                });

                // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
                UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.Delegate = ADSelf;
            }
            else
            {
                // iOS 9 or before
                var allNotificationTypes = UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound;
                var settings = UIUserNotificationSettings.GetSettingsForTypes(allNotificationTypes, null);
                UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterUserNotificationSettings(settings);
            }
```

The key really is the following lines:

```
UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotifications();
```

OR

```
UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterUserNotificationSettings(settings);
```

Comment: I didn't post code because I just paste the sample code. I tried your code but nothing changed. Already checked: APNS development certificate, Entitlements.plist asp-environment entry, UserNotificationCenterDelegate. Plus I use Xamarin.Forms, I tried your code before and after LoadApplication(new App()); I have breakpoints on ReceivedLocalNotification, ReceivedRemoteNotification, 
RegisteredForRemoteNotifications, FailedToRegisterForRemoteNotifications and WillPresentNotification.

Comment: The iPhone is connected via my phone's hotspot, it is possible that my phone blocks some of the necessary ports?

Comment: well in that case, not a clue, if your calling UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotifications(); it should present the user with a dialog box where they select yes or no to allow remote notifications. Your hotspot will not really have an impact on this. If you're using xamarin forms, then you should have listed it as a tag, and mentioned it in your opening post (just FYI). If you're using forms, you still need the above code I listed in the AppDelegate class of the apple project that's part of your forms solution.

Comment: It asks to allow notifications and in the preferences, notifications are enabled. BTW thanks for the question edit.

Comment: Ok so if it is asking for permission to allow remote notifications that means that it has called 'RegisterUserNotificationSettings()' correctly, are you sure you've overriden the didrecieveremotenotifications correctly? honestly it might be worth showing us the code, I realise you said it's lifted from the guide, but just on the off chance it lets us spot something that we might not normally ask for.

Comment: Here it is: `public override void ReceivedRemoteNotification(UIApplication application, NSDictionary userInfo) { }`

Comment: You should be overriding " public override async void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, NSData deviceToken)" that's where you submit the device token to your notification hub. the 'RecievedRemoteNotification' method is only ever hit when a notification comes through, AFTER you've registered your device against the notificaiton hub.

Comment: Sorry I copied the wrong method: `public override void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, NSData deviceToken)
        {
            this.deviceToken = deviceToken.ToString();
        }`

Comment: So in that method, there should be code that connects to your azure notification hub, passes it the device ID and any tags that you might want to use.

Comment: I know but RegisteredForRemoteNotifications is never called. that's the problem.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot register the device if it is a simulated device.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. The fault was, the mobile phone didn't have an active internet connection!